# Appery.io aws S3 integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, appery.io

Looking for help on how to have a appery.io ionic 5 app upload images, files, videos etc. to aws S3.  I am using aws DynamoDB thru API Express successfully and can get a presigned S3 URL thru API Express as well.  My problem is using the presigned URL to upload a image/file. Tried fetch, httpClient etc. Some Guidence would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To work with binary data in API Express you can do the following:

- Create new service of `Custom REST API` type
- In START node select `POST` method and `Binary` for request body
- With that you should be able to select `Binary request` as parameter value in SQL node

The second part of the question is how can you get the binary data if you have `fileUrl`.

- Import API Express service created on a previous step into your project with `Create New > API Express service`
- On `Code` tab create a variable named `buffer` of type `Any`
- On `Data` tab add datasource for the imported API Express service. In `Before send` mapping connect `buffer` with `body.data`
- Drop the button on `Screen1`
- Add event with TypeScript code to it:

```
fetch(fileUrl).then(res => res.arrayBuffer()).then(arrayBuffer => {
    this.buffer = arrayBuffer;
    this.Apperyio.execDataService(this, "myAexService");
});
```